# Excel - Replace cell link in formula with value in cell

Tags: excel

I'm trying to figure clean up a spreadsheet - but I'm trying to avoid typing out a lot of hardcoded values that are referenced in formulas.

So right now, I have a function that takes a string

=FunctionThatWantsAString(A1,SomeOtherInputs)

In Cell A1 I have "SomeString"

Is there a way to easily replace the cell link "A1" in the formula with the string "SomeString"?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple solution is to go to the Formulas ribbon > Defined Names > Name Manager > New [or simply select A1, and then click on the NameBox which says "A1" and type in "SomeString"]

This allows you to name a specified range. You can then refer to that name either within an excel worksheet or within VBA.

**Edit for additional request**
If you don't want A1 to have to hold the text "SomeString", you can actually use the name manager to create a name which refers to a string. ie: you can have the Name SomeString be equal to "asdf". Then, use ctrl+f to find and replace all instances of "A1," in your worksheet with "SomeString".

Alternatively , just use ctrl+f to find and replace "A1" with ""asdf"", and have your results hardcoded directly in all cells. Probably not recommended to do that though, for maintenance purposes.

Comment: Good idea - but in the case doesn't really do what I'm after.  I'm trying to make writing formulas easier for me, because so many of my formulas require these strings - I'm trying to avoid writing them right into the formula bar & b) avoiding having like 3 columns with strings in it.  trying to collapse them into one

Comment: Not sure I understand. If you rename cell A1 as "SomeString" you can write the formula as requested =FunctionThatWantsAString(SomeString,SomeOtherInputs)

Comment: Ah - wait I see now. You don't want to replace typing "A1" with "SomeString", you want to hardcode your formula across the board, so that the only place "SomeString" is stored is "off-workbook".

Comment: Pretty much.  lets say you're trying to build some nasty formula, has a bunch of string inputs.  The input is never going to change, so I just want to hardcode it into the formula.  I'm just too lazy to type out each different string 100 times haha

Comment: See my Edit - I recommend you create the new named Strings, instead of hardcoding them directly - your formulas will look nicer (as they will refer to a simple name, instead of a long string), and it will be easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a User Defined Function, you should check if that first parameter is a cell value, and if so, get the value.

```
Public Function test(st As Variant)

If TypeName(st) = "Range" Then

'get the value of the range or use the string passed in
'or if TypeName(st)="String"
End If

test = TypeName(st)

End Function
```